# Inner and outer wrapper colors

Tags: html, css

That seems to be a dumb question, but I'm really surprised, after a few websites worked with. Why does the **foo** div is red, not green?

https://jsfiddle.net/de8he92v/

```
<div class="wrapper-2">
    <div class="wrapper-1">
        <div>foo</div>
    </div>
</div>

<style>
.wrapper-1 { background-color: red; }
.wrapper-2 { background-color: green; }
</style>
```

## Edit

Ok, I read ThisClark answer, but still don't understand.

Here is updated fiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/de8he92v/3/

Now the **foo** is yellow, but why it is not green?

The **foo** is inside red wrapper. Then, the red wrapper is inside green wrapper. So why we don't see green? What the madness?

In other words, if the puppy is inside the kennel, then we would see the kennel. But here we see only the puppy.

Comment: Because you are place foo div in .wrapper-1.. and div is block element so taking full width

Comment: I think you need to apply or save your last fiddle update. I don't see any yellow at this time.

Comment: See the update in my answer for more visuals that help illustrate the DOM structure.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`<div>foo</div>` has the default user agent styles applied to it which is typically a transparent background and `display: block`.

Since it's inside `.wrapper-1` and has a transparent background, you will see red.

To make this really stand out, add this to your fiddle and run it again:

```
div {
  margin: 5px;
  padding: 5px;
  border: solid black 5px;
}
```

That additional style will apply to all the `div`s on the page and give you a better visual idea of where they are and what styles they have.

With the additional style applied, it ends up looking like this:

[image]

Additionally, `div.wrapper-1` is said to be a child of `div.wrapper-2` and even though 1 comes before 2 in numerical order, the `div.wrapper-1` styles appear on top of their parent element, `div.wrapper-2`. The same parent-child relationship applies between `div.wrapper-1` and `<div>foo</div>`.

**EDIT**

Your updated code in 3D view with margin, padding, and border:

[image]

Your update without additional style:

[image]

Comment: Quote: **"even though 1 comes before 2 in numerical order, the div.wrapper-1 styles appear on top of their parent element, div.wrapper-2".** But why? I mean, if I place an apple inside a red paper, and then I place this "wrapped" apple inside green paper, I would see a green paper. But here I'm see only red. Why?

Comment: The document object model (DOM) which underlies all of this does not work like putting things in bags and bags in bags so that the outermost bag is all you see. Instead, it works more like stacking blocks on top of eachother, or pieces of construction paper. If I stack 3 pieces of construction paper on top of eachother, you will only see the top piece.

Comment: After the 3D pictures, I'm really understand all you said. Fantastic. I think this answer will be upvoted many times in the future :-)